# phpMailer not sending emails to external domains

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am able to send emails to email addresses on the host domain so sending an email to me@domain.com work, where the mail host is domain.com, but if I send it to me@gmail.com it doesn't come through, and I don't get any errors from the phpMailer, with debug on, it shows everything has been done.  Here is my phpMailer setup:

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");                    

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = "mail.mydomain.co.uk"; // specify main and backup server                  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication                  
$mail->Username = "sendmail@mydomain.co.uk"; // SMTP username                   
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password                  
$mail->From = "info@mydomain.com"; //do NOT fake header.                    
$mail->FromName = "Me";                 
$mail->AddAddress("you@gmail.com"); // Email on which you want to send mail                                         
$mail->Subject = "Just a Test";                 
$mail->Body = "Hello. I am testing <b>PHP Mailer.</b>";

if(!$mail->Send()){

    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

}else{

    echo "<p>Thank you, we will be in touch shortly</p>";

}
```

What is going on?  As far as the mailer is concerned it has sent because I get back

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Start mail input; end with . 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed
```

Comment: Have you checked your gmail's Spam folder?

Comment: Yes, I know I wondered that too

Comment: oh sorry, I meant no, its not in spam

Comment: Ask to watch smtp server queue. It might get filtered after getting into the queue.

Comment: ok that would be on the actual hosting server then?

Comment: @Nicola - In that case... can you send to other domains? Try it with Yahoo / Hotmail / whatever you can get. I'd also suggest sending as basic a message as possible, too - skip the From header, for one, and see if that gets through.

Comment: @andrewsi no it doesn't go to hotmail either.  Commented out from header still not going.

Comment: That was the last thing I could think of, alas - hopefully @Alfabravo's suggestion will help.

Comment: Thanks.  Well I'll try that tomorrow when my colleagues back in who knows how to look at smtp server queue

Comment: Does your ISP allow smtp services to be set up like this? Most ISP's dont. You might have to change the $mail->Host to the ISP's smtp-server.

Comment: SMTP problem, recently using google.com/a for emailing and SMTP routing, sometimes emails would take about a day to be delivered

Comment: @Trikks yes it works on another site, we set it up for that so it goes to our internal email address and then forward it out to the client email

Comment: check answer here, working properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006713/phpmailer-not-sending-email-to-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-or-these-are-blocking-email-s/32087402#32087402