# phpmailer not sending email to gmail,yahoo,hotmail or these are blocking email sent by phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am using PHPmailer to send emails

here is code that i have used:

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

        $subject = "test";
        $to = "test_patel@yahoo.com"
        $mail->SetFrom("PDSociety@aol.com","Punjab Dental Society");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("PDSociety@aol.com", "Punjab Dental Society");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($str);
        $mail->AddAddress($to, "Punjab Dental Society");    
        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
          $err = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
          //echo $err;
        } else {
          $msg = "Message sent!";
        }
        // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
```

if i change email address from yahoo to gmail or hotmail, still email are not sent.

i checked by echoing error, but no errors.

can anyone explain what is the issue ?

Comment: Where you have defined the $str?

Comment: it is html content, not assigned value here, but it is not empty

Comment: May be your HTML content is not working.

Comment: ok lets assume $str = "<p>Hello World</p>", stil is is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying various ways, i found following code working with almost all email providers

```
$to['email'] = "recipients email address";      
$to['name'] = "name";   
$subject = "email subject";
$str = "<p>Hello, World</p>";
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();                                     
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'Specify main and backup server here';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'xyz@domainname.com';
$mail->Password = 'email account password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->From = 'From Email Address';
$mail->FromName = "Any Name";
$mail->AddReplyTo('xyz@domainname.com', 'any name'); 
$mail->AddAddress($to['email'],$to['name']);
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: High");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;    
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $str;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
$err = 'Message could not be sent.';
$err .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;                        
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

variable values needs to be changed accordingly.
Hope these helps people having issues with PHPmailer

Comment: what goes into `$mail->Username = 'xyz@domainname.com';`?

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer is only involved in submitting the message to your own mail server, and you're not having any problem there. After that, your mail server takes on the responsibility of sending it on, so you will find the answer in your mail server's logs.

There is no simple way to ensure messages end up in the inbox and not spam - if there was, spammers would be using it and filtering would be useless. Make sure your DNS resolves backwards and forwards, that you have valid SPF records, that you sign your messages with DKIM (especially important for Yahoo) and most importantly, that you don't send messages that your recipients think are spam.

Comment: i made some changes and now it is working with Yahoo, Gmail, but not with hotmail email, not even delivering email to spam folder, any idea ?

Comment: You need to look in your mail server logs. It will tell you what is happening.

Comment: It's not just a lack of errors you're looking for - you should be seeing successful deliveries logged too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);      // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

        $mail->IsSMTP();            // telling the class to use SMTP
        try {
            $mail->AddAddress($to['email'],$to['name']);
            $mail->FromName = '';

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($message);


            $send = true;
            return $mail->Send();

        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo    $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
        }
```

It will help you if any exception error.

Comment: thanx,with this code emails are sent to gmail  but in spam folder, what to do to send in inbox ?

Comment: but not working with yahoo and hotmail, no error shows

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked on the post here: [Using PHPMailer Results in many blocked emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346627/using-phpmailer-results-in-many-blocked-emails)? The asker solved the issue by changing the email subject:

> Well I solved the issue; the code above was not the problem and works
>   great.
>
> In my subject, I used a phrase regarding "verify your account
>   information" and that got it blocked on a few ISP's.
>
> So the lesson is, your subject matters. I was looking at my php code
>   and my body content before I realized this.

The content of the email and its subject can make ISPs ban it. You could try taking the content of one of your received emails from your inbox and see if that goes through.

Comment: i dont think ISP ban it, i have private mail server, with email address xyz@companyname.com, emails are sending to these email addresses but no to yahoo gmail hotmail, with same content and subject

Comment: So the emails goes through to your private server with no spam-filter, but not to yahoo, gmail or hotmails, which all has spam-filters?